# Discriminant of a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, discriminant

Consider the function $f(x)=kx^{2}-2kx+2.$

Find the values of $k$ if $kx^{2}+2>2kx$ for any value of $x$.

I am unsure how to start off this question. I thought it involves the 
discriminant but couldn't figure out which condition to apply. Any help 
will be appreciated.

Comment: If $kx^2+2 > 2kx$, then $kx^2 - 2kx + 2 > 0$. So will the discriminant be positive, negative, or zero?

Comment: Start by finding an expression for the derivative in terms of $k$

Comment: @TobyMak, the discriminant will be negative. But how would anyone know if the end points are inclusive or exclusive? Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is right...

please comment if it is wrong

i) $k>0$

$kx^2-2kx+2>0$

$D=k^2-2k<0$

$0<k<2$

ii) $k=0$

$2>0$ -> True

iii) $k<0$

$kx^2-2kx+2>0$ -> cannot be always true

Therefore, $0\leq k<2$

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: @TobyMak When $k=0$, isn't $2>0$ for any value of $x$?

Comment: Whoops, my bad.